# DataGridView: reordering of columns not saved in DataSource (DataView) and manually editing nearly not possible

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As the title says: I have a DataGridView with a DataView as DataSource. Reordering of columns via drag & drop is not really working because the changes are not written to the DataView.
I tried to catch the ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event and modify the DataTable directly but this causes an exception. I don't know what exactly is causing the exception. I just know that this does not occur when I remove the specific line. The debugger just refers to Program.cs with a System.NullReferenceException.

**this is not working:**

```
private void dgTable_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Index != e.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
              ((DataView)dgTable.DataSource).Table.Columns[e.Column.Name].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
              //no exception when I delete this line
        }
    }
```

**BUT, this is working**

```
private void dgTable_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Index != e.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                dgTable.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    ((DataView)dgTable.DataSource).Table.Columns[e.Column.Name].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
                }));
            }).Start();
        }
    }
```

Yeah I know, I already have a solution but this is a bad one. Could somebody help me out?

**Edit: Solution**

```
private void dgTable_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Index != e.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
            dgTable.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                dgTable.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged -= dgTable_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged;
                ((DataView)dgTable.DataSource).Table.Columns[e.Column.Name].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
                dgTable.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += dgTable_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged;
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Reordering the __display order__ of columns imo __shouldn't__ re-order the columns in the data source. Nor, of course, break the binding..

Comment: `//no exception when I delete this line`  Why would this comment be an issue?

Comment: @LarsTech Not sure if troll or not. I am refering to the line above the comment

Comment: Not a troll.  I don't understand if you delete that line why would there be an exception?

Comment: You could probably just use BeginInvoke without a new thread.  The problem seems to be caused by you changing the data source while the DGV is still executing code related to the event call.  Using BeginInvoke (or your method) is running the code well after the DGV finishes what it's doing.

Comment: @Zer0 thanks! This fixed it. In addition to this I had to remove the EventListener temporarily.